# SQLAlchemy: How to cast string value to date in multiple insert statement?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a list of dict objects

```
data = [
{'id': 1, 'dt':'2002-01-02' },
{'id': 2, 'dt':'2014-01-15' },
{'id': 3, 'dt':'2005-10-20' }
]
```

and a table in sqlite created using sqlalchemy as follows

```
engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
metadata = MetaData()

tbl1 = Table('t1', metadata,
                     Column('the_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                     Column('the_dt', Date))

metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

stmt_insert = tbl1.insert().values(the_id=bindparam('id'), the_dt=bindparam('dt', type_=Date)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt_insert, data)
```

This gives me the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite Date type
>   only accepts Python date objects as input.

What do I assign to the "type_" parameter to make this binding work ?

Comment: in sqlalchemy you can use func.  Example- func.DATE(your date  value as a string)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your `dt` strings to date objects, for instance:

```
import datetime
for item in data:
    item['dt'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['dt'], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

If you don't need the ORM part of SQLAlchemy (no class/table mapping). The easiest way is to tell SQLAlchemy that you use String instead of Date, like this:

```
tbl1 = Table('t1', metadata,
    Column('the_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('the_dt', String))
```

It will work because your date string use ISO 8601 format ("%Y-%m-%d").

But the best practices are:

1. read records from CSV
2. convert data to Python objects (`int`, `date`, etc.)
3. insert data in database.

The conversion can be done in the constructor of the class which is mapped to the table.

**EDIT** A kind of "solution"

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, MetaData, Date, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

metadata = MetaData()
```

I've created a "fake" table with a `String` type instead of a `Date`:

```
fake_tbl1 = Table('t1', metadata,
                  Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                  Column('dt', String))

metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

And insert the data as-is:

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, 'dt': '2002-01-02'},
    {'id': 2, 'dt': '2014-01-15'},
    {'id': 3, 'dt': '2005-10-20'}
]

stmt_insert = fake_tbl1.insert()

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt_insert, data)
```

Then I redefine the same table with the required `Date` field:

```
tbl2 = Table('t1', metadata,
             Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
             Column('dt', Date),
             extend_existing=True)
```

Here is a rows selection:

```
stmt_select = select([tbl2])

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt_select)

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

You'll get:

```
(1, datetime.date(2002, 1, 2))
(2, datetime.date(2014, 1, 15))
(3, datetime.date(2005, 10, 20))
```

This works for your simple case, but I won't recommend this for a generic solution.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. But I wanted to know if there is someway I can do it using the sqlalchemy bindparam function

Comment: Why don't you use a class/table mapping?

Comment: Cos, my requirement is of importing data from a csv file(s) and I didn't need the ORM part of SQLAlchemy. Also just plain curiosity :o)

Comment: Also, Take a look at [SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#sql-expression-language-tutorial). In particular, the topic "Executing Multiple Statements".

Comment: Yes, I've realized that after posting ;-). Well, have you seen my edit **A kind of "solution"**?